# display records based on selection of name from picklist in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to get my hands on learning Visual force.

I have an object inv_*c which holds invoice records and another  object item*_c

I have in my VF page  a picklist with the object names.

If user selects inv_*c then all records of inv*_c are displayed if user selects item__c  all records of item are displayed

Is there any way where the list would be displayed on the completion of the selection or do we have to have button to get it.

how can i achieve this in VF? any small code snippet would be wonderful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a JavaScript onchange event with the help of the ActionSupport Visualforce Component. Here's an example.

```
<!--  Page: -->  

<apex:page controller="exampleCon">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputpanel id="counter">
            <apex:outputText value="Click Me!: {!count}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                                action="{!incrementCounter}" 
                                rerender="counter" status="counterStatus"/>
        </apex:outputpanel>
        <apex:actionStatus id="counterStatus" 
                           startText=" (incrementing...)" 
                           stopText=" (done)"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>    

/***  Controller: ***/  

public class exampleCon {
    Integer count = 0;

    public PageReference incrementCounter() {
            count++;
            return null;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

In your case the actionSupport component would be a child of your selectRadio component i.e.

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!selection}">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" .... />
</apex:selectRadio>
```